# Adding ArcGIS mapserver to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-online

I would like to add "http://www.arcgis.com/" layer to my maps but I'm unable to connect.  After adding the URL into connection details it gives me an error. "Failed to retrieve service cap":  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you provide a sample url that you tried?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way now is to use the [QuickMapServices](http://nextgis.com/blog/quickmapservices/) plugin

[image]